# Using OAuthWebSecurity with Salesforce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, salesforce, single-sign-on

I'm trying to get an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) site to accept Salesforce as an authentication provider, but I am not having any luck. I'll start out with the `IAuthenticationClient` I have so far:

```
public class SalesForceOAuth2Client : OAuth2Client
{
    private readonly String consumerKey;
    private readonly String consumerSecret;

    #if DEBUG
        private const String BaseEndpoint = @"https://test.salesforce.com";
    #else
        private const String BaseEndpoint = @"https://login.salesforce.com";
    #endif

    private const String AuthorizeEndpoint = BaseEndpoint + @"/services/oauth2/authorize";
    private const String TokenEndpoint = BaseEndpoint + @"/services/oauth2/token";
    private const String RevokeEndpoint = BaseEndpoint + @"/services/oauth2/revoke";

    public SalesForceOAuth2Client(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret)
        : base("SalesForce")
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(consumerKey))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("consumerKey");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(consumerSecret))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("consumerSecret");
        }
        this.consumerKey = consumerKey;
        this.consumerSecret = consumerSecret;
    }

    protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
    {
        String redirect_url = returnUrl.AbsoluteUri;

        // Hack to work-around the __provider__ & __sid__ query parameters,
        // but it is ultimately useless.
        /*String state = String.Empty;
        Int32 q = redirect_url.IndexOf('?');
        if (q != -1)
        {
            state = redirect_url.Substring(q + 1);
            redirect_url = redirect_url.Substring(0, q);
        }*/

        var builder = new UriBuilder(AuthorizeEndpoint);
        builder.Query = "response_type=code"
                      + "&client_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.consumerKey)
                      + "&scope=full"
                      + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirect_url)
                      // Part of the above hack (tried to use `state` parameter)
                      /*+ (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(state) ? "&state=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(state) : String.Empty)*/;
        return builder.Uri;
    }

    protected override IDictionary<String, String> GetUserData(String accessToken)
    {
        // I am not sure how to get this yet as everything concrete I've
        // seen uses the service's getUserInfo call (but this service relies
        // heavily on a username, password, token combination. The whole point
        // of using oatuh is to avoid asking the user for his/her credentials)
        // more information about the original call:
        // http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo.htm

        // Return static information for now
        //TODO: Get information dynamically
        return new Dictionary<String, String>
        {
            { "username", "BradChristie" },
            { "name", "Brad Christie" }
        };
    }

    protected override String QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, String authorizationCode)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(TokenEndpoint);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write("grant_type=authorization_code");
            streamWriter.Write("&client_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.consumerKey));
            streamWriter.Write("&client_secret=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.consumerSecret));
            streamWriter.Write("&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.AbsoluteUri));
            streamWriter.Write("&code=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(authorizationCode));
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                String response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response);
                return queryString["access_token"];
            }
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

The primary problem is that `redirect_uri` != `Callback Url`.

Salesforce enforces the callback [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) you supply in the application configuration to match *exactly* to the value provided in `redirect_uri` of `QueryAccessToken`. Unfortunately `OAuthWebSecurity` relies on `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet`, and that library appends two query parameters: `__provider__` and `__sid__`. If I try to remove those (see the hack in `GetServiceLoginUrl`), obviously the login fails because the hand-back doesn't know how to continue on with the request without knowing which provider to use.

To work around this I did notice that the [request](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm) call accepts an optional `state` parameter which is (essentially) there for passing things back and forth across the request/callback. However, with the dependence on `__provider__` and `__sid__` being their own keys having `data=__provider__%3DSalesForce%26__sid__%3D1234567890` is useless.

Is there a work-around without having to fork/recompile the `Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth` library and modify the `OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthenticationCore(HttpContextBase, String)` method to look at `data` first, then continue on to `OpenAuthSecurityMananer.GetProviderName`?

Also, in case the registration mattered (`AuthConfig.cs`):

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(
  new SalesForceOAuth2Client(/*consumerKey*/, /*consumerSecret*/),
  "SalesForce",
  new Dictionary<String, Object>()
);
```

#### Update (11.01.2013)

I just got a response back from Salesforce. It looks like they don't know how to implement [3.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2) of the RFC which means that any query parameters you send in with the `return_uri` are not only ignored, but prohibited (at least when dynamic in nature). So, it looks like I can't use a library that works on *every other platform and follows the standard*--i have to create my own.

Sigh.

Comment: By the way you can ask Salesforce questions directly on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @mast0r: yes, but this is still code based on not really salesforce (as an application) based. If I was asking for a facebook, yahoo, windows live, etc. connector it would still come here.